# Why doesn't TypeScript raise an error when I assign a number to an Object?

Tags: typescript

I would expect an error on this code **TypeScript**:

```
var obj:Object;
var num:number;

obj = 4; // no error!
num = 4; // ok
num = obj; // error.
```

Any good reason for not getting an error?

Comment: Exactly the same type relations exist in Java and C# (Try `Object v = 1;` in both languages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Object**: Provides functionality common to all JavaScript objects.
>
> The Object object is contained in all other JavaScript objects; all of its methods and properties are available in all other objects. - [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/kb6te8d3(v=vs.94).aspx)

It works the way you described because a `number` is an `Object`, but an `Object` isn't necessarily a `number`.